# Will DPM clean up files from SharePoint 2010 RBS

Tags: rbs

I recently setup RBS in our development SharePoint 2010 site to store large documents or videos.  I found out that when you remove the RBS files from SharePoint, and then run RBS Maintainer to remove files from DB, and file server.    The files are removed from DB, but not from the file server until you run the SQL DB backup and log backup, then the RBS files will be removed from the file server.
Since we are NOT using SQL 2008 R2 to back up our SharePoint 2010 site, instead we are using DPM 2012.
Since we do not have DPM installed in our development environment so we cannot test it out.
My question is Does DPM backup the database and database log?  Will it remove  the RBS files?

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question, but... assuming you are using the RBS FILESTREAM provider by Microsoft...

All backup operations that use the VDI (virtual backup device interface) will work as expected as if RBS FILESTREAM isn't even in place (except that the backups are much bigger than standard SQL backups). However... using DPM uses snapshots - which the RBS FILESTREAM provider does not support.

See this blog post for more: http://blog.sharepoint-recovery.com/2012/03/27/implementing-rbs-for-sharepoint-2010-make-sure-to-consider-backup-and-restore-implications/